# Angular one way binding updates the view only once

Tags: angular, data-binding

I'm trying to understand how Angulars one way binding works. In the following code the button only updates the view once and in subsequent clicks has no effect of the view. Can someone please explain why it works like this? It looks to me as the databound  `obj` is set to a new reference object each time the button is clicked. Shouldn't then the view be updated each time the button is clicked?

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="obj;">
   <input #testInput [value]="obj.testValue">
   <button (click)="onClick(5)"></button>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
export class TempComponent {
   constructor() {}

   obj = { testValue: 1 };

   onClick(value: number): void {
       this.obj = { testValue: value };
   }
}
```

Comment: Must be work, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvx7bb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ok nice that you put in StackBlitz. So: Step1. Input value is 3. Step 2. User manually inputs 2, input value is 2. Step 3. User clicks button, input value changes to 5. Step 4. User manually inputs 2. Step 5. User clicks button, value is still 2, why not 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works only once because you are not updating the value when the user changes the value in the input (2-way-binding). Angular compares the value it knows (which is 5 after the first click) with the new value (which is also 5) and determines it does not need to reflect the change in the view because the values are the same. Try it with a different value each time and you will see the difference.

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzvdyr) with randomized numbers.

Comment: Ok this is what I suspected but the actual binding value is a child property of "obj" which gets fully replaced. But that doesn't seem to matter. So if I wanted Angular to reset the value to 5 on each button click could it be done with one way binding or what would be  the preferred way?

Comment: It does not **not** matter but it is only one factor. If you didn't change the reference you would run into problems later on. The preferred way in this case would be to use 2 way binding. You usually don't have an input that the user can type into anyway, if you didn't need the value :)

Answer (score 2):

This has something to do with the Change Detection

So even after multiple clicks, value of `obj.testValue` remains the same. What you enter within the textbox is not set back to `obj.testValue`.

When the Change detection cycle triggers, it checks for every `@Input` property change, In this case the value of `obj.testValue` is never changed (5 always).

So the input bound property `[value]` will not get the new value, since the value associated with `obj.testValue` has not changed.

Instead you can go with two way binding using `ngModel`

`<input [(ngModel)]="obj.test">`

Comment: But obj.testValue is included in the change detection and it is not an @Input. It just doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks BTW, so updating the view with the same value (5) can't be done with one way binding?

Comment: @user10103655 If the value of `obj.testValue` does not change, then Angular will not update the `[value]` during the change detection cycle.

Comment: @user10103655 It can be done with a hack, but why you are avoiding two way data binding here? Either ways, check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agj7rc?file=src/app/app.component.ts I reset and set it back to 5

Answer (score -1):

Angular's one way binding means that a view could get a class field value, but a class field cannot access to view variable (so it only works in one way).

Here, for the first click, you replace the initial value 1 by 5. After that, you assign to obj a new object which has as value 5 for testValue.

If you want to update the view each time the button is clicked, you have to replace

```
 onClick(value: number): void {
       this.obj = { testValue: value };
 }
```

By

```
onClick(value: number): void {
       this.obj.testValue += value;
}
```